# combine Mp3 and Jpeg Image to some light weight format by jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, audio, video

I have images and seperate mp3 in database , and i want to combine both and display in the webpage.

Is there any solution with Jquery and php ?

Comment: What do you mean combine? Just show the image while playing the music (separately), putting a jpg and an mp3 file together (if it were possible) won't magically make a video of it, if that's what you're after

Comment: To learn how to stream mp3 follow **[link](http://nunzioweb.com/streaming_audio-example.htm)** and for putting an image its as simple as <img src='imagelocation' alt='sometext'/>

Comment: @DamienPirsy actually, one image + one audio file ... combine and generate a format and display on a web page.

Comment: @HanutSingh yah.thats one like streaming, can it create a combined light weight format for mobiles ?

Comment: Why do you want to combine them? Just use an ID3 album art tag?

Comment: @HanutSingh can you tell more about ID3 Album tag ?

Comment: This music player will let you show the default album art that is embedded in the mp3 files **[link](http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/)** and ID3 tags are meta data that are included in mp3 files format that specify different properties of the files such as artist composer genre etc